# Java comparator logic. Suggestions for a better way of writing it

Tags: java, comparator

Below is a piece of logic I have written for a CustomComparator but not very satisfied with it. Can anybody give me some suggestions as to how I am improve it.

```
public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<Offer>, Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 8040322980719271561L;

@Override
public int compare(final Offer o1, final Offer o2) {

    int comparisonIndicator = 0;

    if (("B".equals(o1.getStatusInd()))
        && (!("B".equals(o2.getStatusInd())))) {
        comparisonIndicator = -1;
    }
    else if (("B".equals(o2.getStatusInd()))
        && (!("B".equals(o1.getStatusInd())))) {
        comparisonIndicator = 1;
    }
    else if (("PD".equalsIgnoreCase(o1.getOfferPgm()))
        && (!"PD".equalsIgnoreCase(o2.getOfferPgm()))) {
        comparisonIndicator = -1;
    }
    else if (("PD".equalsIgnoreCase(o2.getOfferPgm()))
        && (!"PD".equalsIgnoreCase(o1.getOfferPgm()))) {
        comparisonIndicator = -1;
    }
    return comparisonIndicator;
}
```

}

Comment: What is B and what is PD. What are you trying to compare?

Comment: Explain what you want to do first.

Comment: Can your values be `null`?

Comment: Basically B and PD are some predefined constants for the status indicator and the type of the offer program. And I am passing this comparator in the Arrays.sort() method to get the sorted list of offers.

Comment: I feel what I have written is very clumsy and want to improve on it.

Comment: @Priyanka If those are constants, why not use integers to represent their type. Then you use make use of the natural order. Are there only 2 possible types? If there are more, it looks really odd that you are writing a comparator for them individually.

Comment: Sure user3437460 I'll will use integers to represent their type. But not sure I understood your statement "If there are more, it looks really odd that you are writing a comparator for them individually".

Comment: What should I be doing really in that case.

Answer (score 0):

you can simplify it like this:

```
int status = o1.getStatusInd().toLowerCase().compareTo(o2.getStatusInd().toLowerCase());
if (status == 0)
    status = o1.getOfferPgm().toLowerCase().compareTo(o2.getOfferPgm().toLowerCase());
return status;
```

if `getStatusInd` or `getOfferPgm` can return null, you need to modify this code a little bit to avoid NPE

Comment: @Marvin yep, added comment about it

Comment: why equals() in one case and equalsIgnoreCase() in the other?